# What is the well-established η law for naturals?

Tags: type-theory, natural-numbers, eta-equality

Notation. `≡` means a general equality. Well, $η$ laws are usually judgmental, but sometimes we provide $η$ laws as theorems.

To me $η$ rules are like vibes, because there can be many $η$ laws for the same type. I'm mainly interested in the coproduct type, where we have:

- commuting conversions `split(M, x.f(A), x.f(B)) ≡ f(split(M, x.A, x.B))`
- identity expansion (unsure about the name for this one) `M ≡ split(M, x. inl x, x. inr x)`

I was told the full $η$ law for coproduct looks like this: `f(M) ≡ split(M, x.f(inl x), x.f(inr x))`, this is also how it is written down on [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sum+type).

However, for recursive types, it is less clear. Natural number is a recursive type, but only identity expansion for it is obvious: `M ≡ split(M, zero, x. suc x)` (I hope this clarifies the type of `split` on naturals), the full $η$ law does not seem easy to write down, especially what do I do in the last argument of `split`.

There's a CS SE answer that [said](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/63233/79971) identity expansion to be the $η$ law for naturals, but I wonder how to do the other versions.

Comment: The ultimate eta law should be "given two expressions `G, x : Nat |- M, N : A`, if `G |- M[x/0] = N[x/0]` and `G, x : Nat |- M[x/succ x] = N[x/succ x]` then `M, N` are judgementally equal." But this is probably never mentioned and never given this name because it has zero hope of being implemented.

Comment: So @Trebor, you are just saying case splitting on `x` (but with no “judgmental equality induction hypothesis”) and then applying judgmental equality to each case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it's best to think of $\eta$ laws for inductive types in terms of their categorical semantics as initial algebras. Recall that initiality for $(\mathbb{N},0,\mathsf{succ})$, regarded as an initial algebra of the functor $X \mapsto 1 + X$, means that for any other algebra $(X,z,s)$ of this functor there is a *unique* homomorphism $\mathsf{rec}_{(X,z,s)} : \mathbb{N} \to X$.

For $\mathsf{rec}_{(X,z,s)}$ to be a homomorphism, it must be the case that $\mathsf{rec}_{(X,z,s)}(0) = z$ and $\mathsf{rec}_{(X,z,s)}(\mathsf{succ}(n)) = s(\mathsf{rec}_{(X,z,s)}(n))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which is just another way of stating the $\beta$-law for $\mathbb{N}$. The *$\eta$-law* for $\mathbb{N}$, in its most general form, is then just the requirement that any homomorphism from $(\mathbb{N},0,\mathsf{succ})$ to $(X,z,s)$ is unique, i.e. any $f,g : \mathbb{N} \to X$ such that $f(0) = g(0) = z$ and $f(\mathsf{succ}(n)) = g(\mathsf{succ}(n)) = s(f(n))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ must be such that $f = g$.

In practice, as Trebor mentioned above, it's basically hopeless to implement $\eta$-laws in this fully general form for non-trivial inductive types, so various restrictions of these to more tractable instances often get called "$\eta$-laws" as well.

Comment: I think we should be a bit more precise than "basically hopeless to implement". This $\eta$-law cannot be a definitional equality in a proof assistant because it would make definitional equality undecidable.